# How to organize executable .jar-files

Tags: java, jar

Situation:

In many repositories that are used by multiple users, there are scripts that require the execution of `.jar` files for automation. These repositories are not necessarily Java project repositories. Specifically, some scripts must execute something like `java -jar plantuml.jar "{repositoryfolder}/reference/model.plantuml" -tsvg` on the local machine of the user. It can be assumed that the `java` command is available on each machine.

Problem:

Is there a standard folder location, applicable to both Windows and Linux, where `.jar` files can be found in a machine-independent manner? Alternatively, is there a standard way of defining dependencies, similar to Python's `requirements.txt` file, that allows for installation of command-line tools without hardcoding a specific folder that must be the same on each machine, and without defining a special environment variable that must exist on each machine?

Comment: `user.home` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard folder location, applicable to both Windows and Linux, where .jar files can be found in a machine-independent manner?

jar files are executables. You might as well ask 'is there a standard folder location where applications are found". No, there is not. It's OS-specific.

> Alternatively, is there a standard way of defining dependencies, similar to Python's requirements.txt file, that allows for installation of command-line tools without hardcoding a specific folder that must be the same on each machine

I don't know what `requirements.txt` is, but if a jar file has dependencies (it needs other jar files to operate), yes, there is - that jar file **itself** should include in its manifest a classpath entry. That entry is space-separated and all paths are resolved relative to the dir the executable jar is in. The 'manifest' is the same place you specify the main class. Looks like:

```
/my/appfolder/main.jar
/my/appfolder/dep/guava.jar
/my/appfolder/dep/jdbi.jar
```

with in main.jar's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file (jars are essentially just zips, use the `jar` or `zip` tool to look at em. Build tools build manifest files automatically; if you must do it by hand, the jar tools `-m` option is what you want to look at):

```
Main-Class: com.foo.MyMainClass
Class-Path: dep/guava.jar dep/jdbi.jar
```

At which point you can just doubleclick `main.jar` or run `java -jar /my/appfolder/main.jar` and those deps do not need to be on the classpath (indeed, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is ignored, as is any `-classpath` option passed to the `java` command if you run `java -jar` - **only** the classpath as listed in the manifest is considered). Of course, the jar file itself is on its own classpath, there is no need to list it separately in the `Class-Path` manifest entry.

If you have a jar file that doesn't have a proper classpath, fix the build script that made that jar file, as it is therefore broken.

Most java build tools offer an alternative; the so-called "fat jar", where **all** dependencies are mixed together with the app's own class files, producing one giant jar file that contains everything needed to run the java application. Such a jar file does not need a `Class-Path` entry in its manifest, given that a jar file always includes itself on its own classpath if running as `java -jar`. The downside is that building a jar file nearly a GB large takes a lot of time and is very annoying to transfer into docker images or to other servers. I recommend against fatjarring; the class-path entry is a much better alternative.

The one thing you need to hardcode someplace is the location of that jar file. If you want a standard path that works 'everywhere', the argument you pass to `java -jar` accepts forward slashes even on windows (where they are interpreted as path separators just like backslash would be), and you can obviate the need for that entirely by first `cd`-ing to the right directory and then executing `java -jar myapp.jar`. Ensure the process that copies the jar file(s) to the host system does that in the user's home dir, and you can write a script that works anywhere, assuming that script's working dir is the user home dir. It simply needs to execute:

```
java -jar myapp/myapp.jar
```

which would work on all platforms.

Comment: The problem with Class-Path in a manifest is that it's just an opaque and difficult to maintain version of supplying the same thing in a script, and subject to the same relativization problems

Comment: @G00se That is an entirely incorrect statement. Build tools maintain your dep chain and can fix the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest for you. In contrast to a script, where you either duplicate the work and separately maintain the full file names of all deps in a script __and__ in your build file - a nasty DRY violation (in that its error prone – hard to test, and very annoying) - or write a build tool plugin that does this for you.

Comment: Furthermore, scripts aren't as universal as jars are: jars work the same way on all platforms (just double click them, or execute `java -jar thatjar.jar`) whereas scripts aren't that universal. `#!/bin/sh` doesn't work on windows, for example. There are fancy ways to craft scripts that work on all platforms by (ab)using `REM` and `#` but that's some bizarre hackery that, surely, you cannot possibly be recommending here.

Comment: I wouldn't do either in reality. Unless a fat jar is unfeasibly large (rare), I would always supply one as otherwise it's just asking for the user to break something by moving a file

Comment: You think an app should hold up __when the user decides to just randomly modify / move its files around__? That's... an utterly ridiculous requirement.